# How to merge multiple CSV files with TIME headers?

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple CSV files in the following format:
Suppose I have the following files

file1.csv:

```
15:06:00,16:06:00,00:06:00,18:06:00
111,133,166,126,0
```

file2.csv:

```
15:08:00,16:08:00,17:06:00,18:06:00
123,133,166,126,0
```

file3.csv:

```
15:06:00,16:06:00,17:08:00,18:08:00
123,133,166,126,0
```

how to obtain the following format?

```
15:06:00,15:08:00,16:06:00,16:08:00,17:06:00,17:08:00,18:06:00,18:08:00,00:06:00,18:06:00
111,,133,,,,,,166,126,0
,123,,133,166,,126,,,,0
123,,133,,,166,,126,,,0
```

How can I achieve this?
PS: Please **no hard coded answers** for these files only. I have multiple CSV files with edge caseto apply the solution.

My attempt

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy

file_paths = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv'] 
headers = []
data_rows = []

for file_path in file_paths:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

    headers.append(pd.Series(df.columns))
    data_rows.append(pd.Series(df.iloc[0]))


all_timestamps = pd.Series(pd.concat(headers).unique())

master_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=all_timestamps)


for header, data_row in zip(headers, data_rows):
   
    row = pd.Series(index=all_timestamps, data='')

    
    for time, value in zip(header, data_row):
        row[time] = value
    
   
master_df = master_df.append(row, ignore_index=True)

master_df.to_csv('merged_file.csv', index=False)
```

However, my attempt ignored first values of each CSV files. I do not know how to go any further.
EDIT: You may sort the data as long as you can achieve the expected output. I deleted trailing zeros to articulate the comprehension. I visualized the process I want to achieve below:

[image]

Is there a way of vertical merging to achieve this? What would be methods to achieve this?

Comment: Your files show a trailing 0 that doesn't fall under any of the columns. Is that a copy-paste error? In what column do the zeroes belong?

Comment: And, can you edit the question and clarify what you mean by "data should not be sorted"? Are you saying the input data won't be sorted, or you don't want the output sorted? Your sample result has sorted timestamp columns.

Comment: @ZachYoung I was assuming if there is a way to concatenate all 3 CSV files values(not eaders/columns) vertically. While doing that, headers/columns will be merged into a single header/column. I expect that this merge will keep the order of columns/headers sorted, but values must not be sorted

Comment: @ZachYoung Sorry my confused statement about sorting data. You can sort the data as long as columns and their respective  values are kept as they are, and not assigned to wrong time column. Also, keep in mind that some files goes through midnicht and end up in next day afternoon time.

Comment: Do you have any guarantee that the files start on the same day; any guarantee they end on the same day?

Comment: @ZachYoung not at all. all files have different date. However, I do not care about the date. I only need timestamps as columns to apply deep learning. Please refer to the image in http://www.timeseriesclassification.com/description.php?Dataset=ECG5000

Answer (score 0):

You could have sort of an intermediary step where you dump all of the values to a list.
Then you could run sort() on the list.
Maybe you will have to convert the values to string, timestamp, or whatever will work with sort.

Example :

```
listExample = ["15:08", "15:06", "15:07", "15:10", "16:05", "16:03"]
listExample.sort()

Sorted listExample = ['15:06', '15:07', '15:08', '15:10', '16:03', '16:05']
```

Comment: As I stated in earlier version of my code, there exists codes going through midnight, and then ending up afternoon time of next day. This would mess up the data, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The DictReader and DictWriter from Python's csv module can help you.

You can harness two properties of the DictWriter to solve this problem:

1. you set the order of the output columns when you create/initialize the writer
2. the writer, by default, will "complete" a row that's missing specified columns by inserting an empty string

Like so:

```py
all_rows = [
    {"12:33":  "b", "14:55":  "c", "11:22": "a"},
    {"12:33": "aa", "11:22": "bb"              },
]

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=["11:22", "12:33", "14:55"])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(all_rows)
```

In the output CSV we can see:

1. the column order of [11:22, 12:33, 14:55] set with the `fieldnames` property determined the final order for all rows
2. the missing value of 14:55 in the 2nd row was filled in with an empty string (the trailing comma)

```
11:22,12:33,14:55
a,b,c
bb,aa,
```

Your solution needs to loop over the files and add each row into a big list, like all_rows above. Some rows will have keys (column names) that others don't. You'll then need to gather all the column names into a single list and sort that list.  Finally, you can create the DictWriter with that final list of column names, write the header, write the rows:

```py
import csv
import glob


all_rows = []
for fname in sorted(glob.glob("input*.csv")):
    with open(fname, newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        all_rows.extend(reader)


col_names: set[str] = set()
for row in all_rows:
    for col_name in row:
        col_names.add(col_name)


with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=sorted(col_names))
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(all_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your output stems from the fact that each row other than the header in your csv files ends with a 0, so Pandas is parsing the first column in each row as the row name, and then skewing all other assignments. Altering your preprocessing step to eliminate the trailing zero, you get:

```
import pandas as pd

file_paths = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv'] 
headers = []
data_rows = []

for file_path in file_paths:
    file = open(file_path, 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    headers.append(lines[0].rstrip().split(','))
    for line in lines[1:]:
        data_rows.append(line.split(',')[:-1])

all_timestamps = list(set([h for header in headers for h in header]))

master_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=all_timestamps)
for header, data_row in zip(headers, data_rows):
    row = pd.Series(index=all_timestamps, data='')
    for time, value in zip(header, data_row):
        row[time] = value
    master_df = pd.concat([master_df, pd.DataFrame([row])], ignore_index=True)

master_df.to_csv('merged_file.csv', index=False)
```

Do note that the columns will be in no particular order. To produce the output exactly as you state, you need to sort. One alternative to address the issue of starting in the afternoon is going through each header and adding 24 to every timestamp which is smaller than its predecessor and then undoing that in the final output. Hope that helps.

Comment: So, should I write if elif condition for all timestamps to eliminate going through midnight case? If so, how can I make sure order of rows will be same?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Row order is preserved because of sequential processing, you can validate that in the example itself. As for timestamps, if you can be sure that each set of files spans less than 24 hours, you can simply keep track of the start time (the earliest timestamp in the first column), sort `all_timestamps`, and then split it on the start time and move the lower part (midnight till start time) to the end. But if overlapping timestamps in different days are possible, then yes, you will need some extra processing of the headers in each file (`line[0]` in my code).

Comment: I see now that in your example files span longer than 24 hours. You could concoct a quirky solution as I suggested in my answer that assumes that whenever the date changes you can recognize it because the time in a given column will be *earlier" than the time in a previous column in the same file. But there may be edge cases where that fails, so I should first ask the obvious: why not include the date?

Comment: I restructured my data so that I add date 1900-01-01 to each TIME column value and rename it to VIZ_DATETIME. I increment the day if I see 00.  At the end, I have this structure: 1900-01-01 10:05:00. How should I use this then then to obtain my goal output?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of considering only TIME, I added date to timestamps.

```py
# Initialize the VIZ_DATETIME column
largest_group['VIZ_DATETIME'] = pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01')

# Add the time to the base date
largest_group['VIZ_DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(largest_group.VIZ_DATETIME.astype(str) + ' ' + largest_group.TIME.astype(str))

# Adjust the day for times past midnight
# To determine the rollover, we check if the current time is less than the previous time.
largest_group['VIZ_DATETIME'] += largest_group['TIME'].diff().lt(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0)).cumsum() * pd.Timedelta(days=1)
largest_group['VIZ_DATETIME'] = largest_group['VIZ_DATETIME'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Then,I initialized a list to hold DataFrames. Loaded each CSV file into a DataFrame and append it to the list. I perform operations with iteration, and sorted the dataframe. Then, created a dictionary and populated with data.

```py
dataframes = []


for file in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df['VIZ_DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['VIZ_DATETIME'])
    df = df.sort_values(by='VIZ_DATETIME')
    dataframes.append(df)


all_datetimes = set()
for df in dataframes:
    # Extract times and merge with all_datetimes
    df_times = df['VIZ_DATETIME'].dt.time
    all_datetimes |= set(df['VIZ_DATETIME'])

# Sort all_datetimes
all_datetimes = sorted(all_datetimes)

# Create a dictionary for the new DataFrame using datetime
output_dict = {datetime: [None] * len(dataframes) for datetime in all_datetimes}

# Populate the dictionary with data
for datetime in all_datetimes:
    for i, df in enumerate(dataframes):
        if datetime in df['VIZ_DATETIME'].values:
            output_dict[datetime][i] = df.loc[df['VIZ_DATETIME'] == datetime, 'VALUE1'].values[0]

# Create the output DataFrame
output_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(output_dict, orient='index')
output_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
output_df.columns = ['Time'] + [f'File{i+1}' for i in range(len(dataframes))]
```